# How do I create a mapview with titanium appcelerator mobile?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I just start to work with [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) and I haven't found a good layout tutorial yet.
At the moment I try to show a mapview with a specific location. Has anybody an example or a good pointer on how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download the [KitchenSink](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/kitchensink) which is mentioned on the [Getting Started page](http://developer.appcelerator.com/get_started).  It has several hundred examples on how to use the various Titanium based APIs - including MapViews.

Here's a simple example

```
    var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region:{latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993, latitudeDelta:0.5, longitudeDelta:0.5},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true
});
win.add(mapview);
```